# how to check whether any item of a list present in the key values in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

i want to discard the values if the value contains any one of the list item. how to write linq for discarding some values from the list object.
i want to make a list of cities to discard from the list of items.

```
string[] city= {"Hyd", "Bangalore", "Mumbai", "Kolkata"};
var data = fields
    .FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Name =="City" 
        && (x.Value !="Hyd" && x.Value !="Bangalore"))
    ?.Value.Replace("A !","");
```

data = Bangalore(should be discarded)

data = delhi (OK)

Comment: What is `fields`? Please provide a [mcve] so we don't have to guess at your requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly you can use `Contains` and negate it's result:

```cs
var filtered = fields
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name =="City" && !city.Contains(x.Value));
```

Comment: if the data is "XYZ Hyd ABC", then it should not discard. value we should get XYZ Hyd ABC

Comment: @krishnamohan not following. This is not `string.Contains`, this is `Enumerable.Contains` it uses exact match, i.e. the code above will filter out only values exactly matching the values in `city` string array.

Comment: @krishnamohan: If you have cases that aren't demonstrated in your question, you should update your question to clarify it.